# Is there a way to determine the average/weighted votes for a question by tag?

Tags: discussion, statistics, voting

From my limited experience on the site it seems that questions in some categories attract more votes than others regardless of (my opinion of) their quality. This may be because there are many more people with an interest in that area, so there's a larger pool of people likely to vote. This seems to lead to fairly basic questions that everyone has a view on attracting scores of votes, while niche questions attract a handful.

Another possible reason would be if there are any philosophical differences between sub-groups. For instance I'd be interested in seeing if people tend to vote differently between .NET and Java. Do Java users vote more or less? Do answerers in each category vote more or less?

So now the questions. 
Is it possible to see average votes by tag?
Can we determine the number of people "active" in a tag?

Comment: I admit I'm rather interested in the average answer score per tag. )

Answer (score 3):

Rather than the data dump most users should instead work directly with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) which allows you to build queries in a basic read only SQL enviornment without downloading any data or tools to read SE's data dumps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess the best way to answer this is to download the [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/creative-commons-data-dump-july-09/) - then you can work out whatever queries you want.

I do agree that some tags definitely receive more interest and votes than others - I don't find that surprising though... in fact, it's pretty much guaranteed to happen.

If you do think of some interesting queries to run, I for one would like to see the results (and the queries themselves) - if you could edit your question with anything you find, that would be great.

Comment: I agree it is likely to happen, thanks for the link to the dump, will have a play and post anything interesting.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/data-dump-sandbox http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/