# Are different topics/tags more generous with upvoting?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to determine the average/weighted votes for a question by tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4460/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-average-weighted-votes-for-a-question-by-tag)

I was wondering if it was possible to find out which tags/topics were the "most generous"... perhaps against:

- average upvotes per question (though this is perhaps a measure of popularity of a tag)
- average upvotes per question / average views per question (of course, this could be a measure of how rubbish the average questions is...)
- similarly for answers

I think it would be interesting to see if java users were "more generous" than python users, or if things were broadly the same.

Is it possible to see any of these stats? Do you think there is large variances in generosity?

Comment: You could probably work out something with the Data Explorer site http://data.stackexchange.com/ something like average votes per question per 100 views or something

Comment: @BenBrocka I did not know about that site! Fantastic.

Comment: In my experience, entries with catchy titles tend to collect a disproportionate amount of views and votes. For example, [my top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11738996/335858) would have never attracted so many voters had it not been for a certain "air of mystery" in its title. And it's a trivial answer, too! What I am trying to say is that a relative tag "generosity" may prove to be a somewhat useless measure.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think "air of mystery" can go one of two ways: either annoying people and it being downvoted/closed or upvoted...which one seems random!

Comment: @haydoni Well, in case of my answer, people upvoted the mysterious question more often: the ratio was 4.25 upvotes to one downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You could [extend this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1256/most-and-least-dangerous-tags-to-answer-among-the-tags-with-1000-questions) a bit for your answers.  It already shows the ratio of upvotes to downvotes within many tags.